# git push origin $BranchName - redirects to https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in

Tags: git, gitlab, branch, git-branch

So I am logged into Gitlab in Chrome but from the command line I am signed in then try to push and get the following result:

```
    git push origin $BranchName

    fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:

  asked for: https://gitlab.com/the-project/the-task/$BranchName.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack

   redirect: https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in
```

I am getting the same error from the git command line and from the GitHub desktop gui.

Comment: have you tried `gitlab ` instead of `git`?

Comment: @RobertMc Are you referring to gitlab push origin $BranchName?  I tried this from the Git CMD but gitlab is not recognized as a command.

Comment: My mistake, I thought I had used that with gitlab in the past, but you're right, it doesn't exist.

Comment: @RobertMc Have you run into this problem before?  What would you propose we try next?

Comment: Maybe the url is wrong? Try `https://gitlab.com/the-project/the-task/$BranchName.git`

Comment: I found the problem - putting the dollar sign at the beginning of the name caused the command line to treat it as a variable. The variable was empty and the command did not want an empty string at that location.  I removed the dollar sign and things worked much better.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem - putting the dollar sign at the beginning of the name caused the command line to treat it as a variable. The variable was empty and the command did not want an empty string at that location. I removed the dollar sign and things worked much better.